# How to get Vue to catch event?

Tags: vue.js, vue-events

Edited to correct unreported syntax error (see comments). It now works as desired.

I'm having trouble getting my event handler to fire in the following Vue code.

As you see, there are two components, `posts` and `post`, and a root `Vue` instance. The button in the `post` template should fire the `remove` event, which is captured by the `v-on:remove` handler in `posts` which calls `posts.deleteItem` with the index of the post. Can someone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

```js
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>Posts</title>
            <!--link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /-->
        <script src="../vue.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">
                <posts></posts>
            </div>
            <script>
                window.onload = function() {

                    // A post
                    Vue.component('post-item', {
                            props: ['post'],
                            data: function() {
                                return {
                                    editing: false,
                                    _cachedItem: ''
                                }
                            },
                            methods: {
                                deleteItem(postId) {
                                    debugger
                                    this.$emit('remove', event.target.value);
                                },
                            },
                            template: `
                                <div v-on:remove="deleteItem">
                                    <li v-show="!editing">
                                        <p v-html="post.text"></p>
                                            <button v-on:click="$emit('remove')">Delete</button>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            `
                    })

                    Vue.component('posts', {
                            data: function() {
                                return {
                                    posts: [
                                        {id: 0, text: "Day at beach"},
                                        {id: 1, text: "Carving the canyons"},
                                        {id: 2, text: "Kickin' it"}
                                    ],
                                };
                            },
                            methods: {
                                deleteItem(index) {
                                    debugger
                                    this.posts.splice(index, 1);
                                }
                            },
                            template: `
                                <div>
                                    <ol>
                                        <post-item
                                                v-for="(post, index) in posts"
                                                v-bind:post="post"
                                                v-bind:key="post.id"
                                                v-on:remove="deleteItem(index)" />
                                    </ol>
                                </div>
                            `
                    });

                    // Root Vue instance
                    new Vue({
                            el: '#app'
                    });

                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: _"It now works as desired"_ <- looks to me like clicking delete removes all the posts. You need to use `this.posts.splice(postId, 1)`

Comment: I replaced the code and believe it should now work as long as `vue.js` is in the script's parent directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're getting a little confused with the event creation and handling.

Events are emitted up to parent components. You don't typically add an event listener within the same component.

All you really need in your `post-item` component is to emit the `remove` event with the appropriate data (ie, the `post` object)

```html
<div>
  <li v-show="!editing">
    <p v-html="post.text"></p>
    <button @click="$emit('remove', post)">Delete</button>
  </li>
</div>
```

Then in your parent component (`posts`), listen for this event on the `post-item` component and assign the event handler

```html
<post-item v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id" :post="post" @remove="deleteItem" />
```

and handle the event with `post` payload

```js
methods: {
  deleteItem (post) {
    this.posts.splice(this.posts.indexOf(post), 1)
  }
}
```

The `post` object emitted by the `post-item` component should be the very same object passed in to its `prop` which is why you can directly use `this.posts.indexOf(post)`. There's no need to go searching for matching `id` properties.

Comment: I'm an idiot. There's a misplaced '>' on `<post-item ...>`. Looking it over to make your suggested changes helped me spot it.

Comment: @TomRussell ah yes, I see it in your question code. That's why I like self-closing tags like in my answer

Comment: Yes. Still no syntax error but easily-spotted `v-on:remove="deleteItem(post.id)"` on the rendered page.